# Angular placeholder only working in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

So I have a variable (defined by $scope.foo) which I use in the html with {{foo}}.

If I have this code:

```
$scope.foo = 'bar';
```

The html will show me bar in chrome but in firefox and edge it will just show {{foo}}

The consoles of the browsers won't show any errors and I'm using Angular 1.

I appreciate any sort of help!

Comment: Are you sure that your html tags are closed? Especially the ones with the ng-app and ng-controller on.

Comment: Yes. One thing to note is that it works when I set the foo variable on the rootScope but not on the scope (note that the controller is registered with the route and not with a directive)

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following snippet on both Chrome and Firefox:

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.foo= 'bar';
    }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>AngularJS Example</title>

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>{{foo}}</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```